# objective-c Align UILabe to right inside UitableViewCell using AutoResizingMask

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autoresizingmask

I am creating an iPhone app, now i am trying to align a `uilabel` inside custom tableview cell to the right using autoresizing mask, i am doing it in interface builder and i am using storyboards, but the problem i am having is that the label just disappears when i run app in iphone 6 simulator, the autoresizing is working fine when i align label to the left of table view cell, but strangely it is not working when i try to align the label right of table view cell, how should i do this?

Note: i don't need to align the uilabel text but need to align the uilabel itself to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the answer is used for my project , please customize the x, y , width and height  as you need

I also face the same problem , SO i follow this method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.yourlableName.frame=CGRectMake(add your label x - position,add your label Y position, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width- add your label width, add your label Height ); for example in your iPhone 4 width is 320 so reduce the width 320-yourlabel width,
```

else part call this line in your custom cell class

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

     cell.yourlableName.frame=CGRectMake(180.0f,220.0f, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-216.0f, 19.0f); 

   }
```

its working fine for me in all device it shows in right side perfectly.

Comment: its working fine for me in all device it shows in right side perfectly

Comment: Anbu.Karthik, its not working for me, what i am getting is that first 3 to 4 rows of table view not showing the label, label appears in 5th row and also not aligning right but more towards the centre of table view cell from right.

Comment: here is part of my cellforrowatindexpath - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OrderCellIdentifiers";
    OrderTableViewCell  *cell=(OrderTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(layoutMargins)]){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
    
    
    cell.statusOrValueLabel.frame=CGRectMake(180.0f,220.0f, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-216.0f, 19.0f); return cell;}

Comment: bro sry wait I update my answer, the answer is used for my project , please customize the x, y , width and height  as you need

Comment: I updated my answer bro please verify, let try and tell me bro u get the correct answer or not